# Tomee+ resource is not available error on resource in subfolder

Tags: jsp, struts-1, apache-tomee

Gotten some 404 errors that I just couldn't quite figure out.

my webapp directory looks like this:

[image]

Tomee has no problem serving up those jsp files that reside at the root of the webapp.  But if any of those jsp file references anything in sub-directories like header, stylesheets, or images, it fails to serve them.

For example, if I do below, I get 404 error:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The problem turns out to be caused by this app was using a servlet name, "default",  that is reserved for tomcat:  https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/default-servlet.html.

So, after I removed this from the web.xml, it starts to work:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
    <jsp-file>/default.jsp</jsp-file>
    <load-on-startup>-1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/default.jsp</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```